# How to define a texstudio newenvironment command with \item in cwl

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I have a class for which I've written a custom environment. I'm trying to add this environment to the `.cwl` file, so that it would properly autocomplete.

Right now I have:

```
%.cwl
\begin{myenv}{command%text}
\end{myenv}
```

Which autocompletes as:

```
%.tex
\begin{myenv}{command}
    content...
\end{myenv}
```

What I want is:

```
%.tex
\begin{myenv}{command}
    \item
\end{myenv}
```

How can I achieve that?

Also, any pointers on where to find material on how to write cwl files (and how to distribute them with your class) would be appreciated. I'm finding TeXstudio documentation on them somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
%.cwl
\begin{myenv}{command%text}\item
\end{myenv}
```

My you find also useful:

- [Update the default autocompletion of `itemize` in TeXStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164105/214241)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534405/214241
- https://texstudio-org.github.io/background.html#description-of-the-cwl-format

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything, but thanks for responding. I'll be sure to give it another stab when I have the time ... This problem got sidetracked since I posted it.

Answer (score 2):

The following cwl code seems to work.

```
\begin{myenv}{command%text}%\\item %\\end{myenv}
```

Or this one for positionning cursor just after item.

```
\begin{myenv}{command%text}%\\item %<%>%\\end{myenv}
```

Comment: Source : https://www.mathematex.fr/viewtopic.php?t=18097