# How to create a autocomplete list for my own packages in TeXstudio?

Tags: packages, texstudio, auto-completion

After learning how to create my own commands and how to make them available in TeXstudio through a autocomplete list with a `.cwl` file, I could not do the same with packages files I created with those commands.

The following example is the autocomplete list for my own command named `myclock`.

[image]

A very well summarized explanation is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/140133).

I read the [latex-document.cwl](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/completion/latex-document.cwl), that show us the basics of TeXstudio default autocompletion, as the following figure presents,

[image]

and also section [4.14 Description of the cwl format](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) of TeXstudio manual, which gives the whole set of instructions to create own `.cwl` files, and this [FAQ of TeXstudio](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion).

Unfortunately I still could not create a completion list for my own packages.

When I start typing a package name inside `\usepackage{ }`, or use the combination `Ctrl+Space`, the list appears with all packages TeXstudio recognizes.

[image]

#### **But what should I do to insert `myownpackage` list in the autocompletion list of packages?**

The basic idea I had didn't work.

[image]

The following figures show an attempt that clearly is not the desired result. The first line replaces the original setup, which is not desirable.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `cwl` file to achieve this.

All you need to is place the `sty` of your package in the folder for local packages in your installation directory:

[image]

After that you have to update the file name database:
**TeXLive**: run a `texhash` on your system, or update via the `tlmgr`.
**MiKTeX**: open the MiKTeX console and follow these instructions ([taken from here](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console)):

[image]

After the database is updated
TeXstudio knows your package exists:

[image]

Comment: Hi @schoekling, I think I need some help. I'm a windows user, and `texhash` is a Linux command. I checked [this link](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/texhash.html) and learned about `mktexlsr`, but I couldn't understand nor find its syntax. I tried some combinations using DOS (typing commands) and MikTeX console (update/refresh options) but without success. I know MikTeX finds my `texmf`, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: I am a Windows user too, but I am using TeXlive and sometimes forget not everyone does, sorry. I'm not familiar with any MiKTeX commands, but it looks like you can update the file database via the MiKTeX Console. I've added a link and screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, It will not be that simple. I've being using RFND (Refresh File Name Database) for long. This operation is necessary after any update on my own packages. I just used it and the autocomplete for pacakge's names still doesn't work. The option "Update package database" still doesn't seem to work.
With your answer, it seems it is not a TeXstudio related issue, but a MikTeX related issue.

Comment: In that case, I am sorry I cannot help with that. I am aware that MiKTeX is usually the recommended option for Windows users, but from my personal experience TeXLive works just as well, if not better (except for [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588073/163512), which can be resolved and probably affects like 0.01% of users).