# luatexja-preset 'yu-win10' not working under Win10

Tags: luatex, luaotfload, japanese

Since some update (see edit), I have not been able to compile files containing Japanese text using the `yu-win10` preset provided by `luatexja-preset` under Windows 10.
However, if I compile the same code using an identical TeXLive installation under the Ubuntu 20.04 subsystem for Windows 10 (with access to Windows' fonts), everything runs perfectly fine.
I have tested this on different machines, and the result is always the same. (Other font presets like `haranoaji` work with both systems.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[yu-win10,deluxe]{luatexja-preset}

\begin{document}
    \section{A Section}
    Some meaningless text.
        
    \section{次のセクション}
    
    意味のないテキスト。
\end{document}
```

Running this with TeXLive under **Windows 10** yields the following error:

[image]

[image]

But letting the **Ubuntu subsystem** handle things works:

[image]
[image]

For some time keeping older versions of `luatexja`, `fontspec`, and `luaotfload` worked as well, but after incompatibilities with other packages kept piling up, I have been using the subsystem for Japanese documents until now - hoping for an update. As I am switching to a new computer, I was hoping to solve this issue, eliminating the need for two TeXLive installations...

Since compiling with Windows takes quite long before producing that error message, I am guessing LuaLaTeX gets stuck in a loop somewhere until it crashes.
Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be and how to solve it?

---

**Edit:**

These are the backup files of the last release numbers where everything worked fine under Windows:

[image]

Comment: some cjk fonts are very large. It can help to compile once with a 64bit binary to create the lua/luc-file of the font. For windows you get them from http://w32tex.org.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it took me a while to understand what's the problem, but now it works. What I thought to be an update that introduced a bug, was just one for one of the packages that pushed the required memory over 4GB... There was an extra steps necessary, so I'll post an answer with the whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the 64bit binaries, as @UlrikeFischer suggested, solved the issue. I monitored the first working compilation in the task manager and luatex.exe clocked out at around 4.1GB, which explains why it crashed earlier (4 is the limit for 32bit).

The steps necessary to get everything working:

1. download tl-win64.zip from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/w32tex/TLW64) and unpack it in your TeXLive directory. To check if you were in the correct directory, make sure your `bin` folder looks like this:

[image]

2. Add the new `win64` folder to your PATH ([my what?](https://superuser.com/a/949577)). Make sure it is listed *before* `win32`!
3. Although not stated in the ReadMe-instructions, you have to run the command (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > `cmd` >) `fmtutil-sys --all`. This will run for a while.
   <sup>leaving this step out won't let any compiler start properly, which was my problem for some time...</sup>
4. Now compile any `.tex` file containing `\usepackage[yu-win10]{luatexja-preset}`. The first compilation is going to take very long, don't worry or interrupt the process.

After the first compilation, future documents should compile in regular compilation time.