# Is there a way to change the default autofill of \begin{figure}?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Eg. I want  it to, when I type `\begin{figure}` and press enter, autocomplete the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
   \caption{}
   \label{}
\end{figure}
```

I am using TexStudio and `\usepackage{graphicx}`

I know that when I type for example `\begin{itemize}`, it autocompletes the following:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item
\end{itemize}
```

So my question is: **Is there a way to customize what autocompletes when entering certain commands?**

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a macro and give a shortcut to it.

Comment: Also if you use `\centering` all the time, you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53383/56823.

Comment: Technically, this is an editor question, not a LaTeX question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a macro as mentioned by @Sigur, or define the autocompletion in your own cwl. For example, you can create a file `usercmds.cwl` containing

```
# usercmds.cwl
\begin{figure}[!htb]%\  \centering%\    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}%\  \caption{}%\    \label{}%\\end{figure}
```

and follow the instructions outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534405/208544) to permanently activate completion from this cwl.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution I have is to create a macro `\myfigure`.
You can add a shortcut to it or have the command to automatically replace it. Here is the config

[image]